# Trying to create an HOC with a curry function but also needs to accept GraphQL data props (react, apollo, GraphQL, recompose)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, recompose

I'm using React, recompose, and apollo GraphQL

I'm trying to create UI authorization (backend auth will be there as well) to allow users with a specific role to enter pages that only they authorized to enter. I'm going off of an [article](https://hackernoon.com/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4) that I found helpful.

In the article, he uses static props. I need to pass props from a data query that I compose together with my Authorization component in an index.js file.

Currently my code looks like the following:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

    const Authorization = ({ props }) => allowAccess => MyComponent => {

      const { viewer: { role } } =  props.data

      return (
        ( allowAccess.include(role) ) ? <MyComponent /> : <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }

    export default Authorization
```

In another file I created variables that hold roles that are allowed to access pages, same as the article referenced above:

```
    export const admin = ['owner', 'admin']
    export const user = ['owner', 'admin', 'user']
```

Then I import this file and my Auth into the file I define my routes. I do the same as the author did in the article and define the roles that will wrap a route component based on who is allowed to view the page:

```
    const Admin = Authorization(admin)
    const User = Authorization(user)
```

[This is where I'm being thrown an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOkbn.png)

What I *think* it happening is it's trying to find a graphql props on the array of user roles I'm passing instead of on Authorization.

Comment: try removing the brackets from the authorization parameter. 

`({ props })` to `(props)`

Comment: and try setting Owner = <Authorization data={admin} />

Comment: thanks, I tried that but I still get the same error (taking curly brackets from props)

Comment: same error if I try setting it to an Authorization component

Comment: create a code pen project, link it here, and i'll help